# result of call uppercased is unused

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have a dynamic table cell that is grouped pragmatically. I need to uppercase the header inside of `willDisplayHeaderView`. I have no success.

**Inside willDisplayHeaderView:**

```
let title = UILabel()
title.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 13)!
title.text?.uppercased() // result of call uppercased is unused

let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
header.textLabel?.font = title.font
// header.textLabel?.text = title.text?.uppercased() // nothing shows
```

With this in mind, I assume all should be well with my above code:

```
let title = "stackover flow gives me all the answers"
title.uppercased() // STACKOVER FLOW GIVES ME ALL THE ANSWERS
```

How to uppercase my header title?

**Edit**

To conclude, and as per [dfri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573247/dfri), text is will always be nil. Instead, `uppercased()` the source and for me that was in `titleForHeaderInSection`. Problem solved.

Comment: `uppercased()` is not a mutating method, so calling it without capturing the return _result_ will yield a warning that the result of the call is unused. If you'd like to uppercase the `text` property of the `title` label, you need to assign the result of the call to `uppercase` (on the possible existing `text`) back to the text property. E.g., `title.text = title.text?.uppercased()`. In case the `text` property is `nil`, by optional chaining this assignment will have no effect, as the result of the chained call will be `nil`. Above, you never set a value to this `text` property, so it's `nil`.

Comment: @luk2302 Yea I've tried that, see my my code in post but the header text no longer shows. Weird. There is nothing else inside of `willDisplayHeaderView` to show.

Comment: @Sylar, my code is different than yours, the first `?` is a `!`.

Comment: @luk2302 in this case, your first `!` approach only adds risk (but no gain). You can actually "optionally conditionally" assign a value to an optional, only in case the optional is not nil. (See [the example in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/52636d9fc34ad1d14302442548a38dda)).

Comment: @dfri are you sure? I was under the impression that the result of `header.textLabel?.text = ...` never assigns anything to the `text` property of  `header.textLabel`.

Comment: Ohh I'm getting crashes about `title` is `nil`. It's not `nil` or is it?

Comment: @luk2302 it's a bit of an obscure feature, but it actually assigns only if the result of the optional chaining is non-`nil`, in which case the return of the expression is `.some(())` (and the assignment is a side effect), whereas if the lhs is `nil`, the result of the expression is `nil` (and no assignment is performed).

Comment: @Sylar: in your example above the `text` property of the `UILabel` `title` is never set to a value, so it is `nil` by default. Now, you can't uppercase something that is `nil`. What is the content your want the `text` property to have; do you extract it from somewhere or do you statically set it to a value within you method? `uppercased()` is simply `String` manipulation, whereas your issue is that you have no `String` instance to manipulate upon to begin with.

Comment: @dfri (more coffee is needed) (slapped the face) Yes you are correct. That's in `titleForHeaderInSection` Thanks for that.

Comment: Since this is solved for you, and the question itself is kind of vague for future readers, I believe we can close this question as "cannot be reproduced / simple typographical error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
title.text?.uppercased()
```

calls the uppercased method of String, which RETURNS an uppercase string. In order to actually assign it to your title, you need to ASSIGN the returned value:

```
title.text = title.text!.uppercased()
```

Or just uppercase the source String and assign immediately, rather than first assigning the lowercase String, if possible.

Comment: What if this is the first assignment to `title.text`, and `title.text` equals `nil` prior to the assignment? Then the forced unwrapping of `text` will yield a runtime exception. Since `title.text` is an optional, there is absolutely no need to unwrap an optional when assigning to it: just use optional chaining instead (`title.text?.uppercased()`). The problem in the OPs case, though, is that `title.text` is never instantiated with a non-`nil` value to begin with (so there is nothing to uppercase!).

Comment: You're right! I was confused by the OP's code, where he first uses var title as a UILabel, and then as a String. Sylar, you are actually making two mistakes: A newly-initted UILabel does not have an assigned text value, AND uppercased() does not assign a value. @dfri: you are correct, my answer is incomplete.

Comment: Hi and thanks. It was just made clear that because of `let title = UILabel()`, `title` will always be `nil` so `uppercased()` will not do anything.